# Bayes specify informative and uninformative prior

Tags: self-study, bayesian, prior, geometric-distribution

I would be really thankful for any hint

Let $x_1,\dots x_n$ be a sample from a geometric distribution with probability parameter $\theta$

$f(x_i\mid \theta)=\theta(1-\theta)^{x_i}$

The likelihood is given by $L(\theta\mid x_i, \dots, x_n)=\prod_i f(x_i\mid \theta)$
Assume we have observed a sample of size n=5 with values $x_i=5,6,9,5,4$. Specify a) an informative prior, (b) and uninformative prior, and determine the posterior distribution for each setting. Make a plot of prior, likelihood and posterior distribution.

Comment: Any hint would be really useful

Comment: Prior for what parameter(s) in what model?

Comment: Geometric likelihood

Comment: do you have any information on which to inform the prior?

Comment: On the conjugate prior distribution for theta.@David

Comment: your statement has no information. What are the units?

Comment: This is all I got! It is a basic statistic course so should be easy @David

Comment: okay. Sounds like you can just make up the information contained in the informative prior, but you need to know what distribution to use for the prior. Do you know the conjugate prior for a geometric distribution?

Comment: I suppose the conjugate prior is a beta distribution. @David.

Comment: A beta would be conjugate for $\theta$ in that model.

Comment: Now that you've edited it enough to be able to begin to answer it, this now appears to be almost a duplicate of [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50575/find-the-conjugate-prior), with one small change (the split into informative priors and uninformative priors, assuming the intent is still that they be conjugate). Do you know what an uninformative prior is? Can you write down the functional form of the conjugate prior?

Comment: I can write down the conjugate prior but don't know how to determine the posterior distribution for each setting.@Glen_b

Comment: Anybody? Some hint what to do then with the beta conjugate? @Glen_b

Comment: The form of the posterior for a Beta-Geometric model is given on the wikipedia article for geometric distributions.

Comment: @jerad thank you but I know that. Just what to do next. How to solve the second part of the question? Where to put the data and how to make a plot of prior, likelihood and posterior distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where to put the data

The data values go into the likelihood. The likelihood is a product of $f(x_i\mid \theta)$, one for each data value. You just substitute the data into the formula you gave!

Your data are $x_i$ values. The first data point is $x_1$, and so on. Your likelihood is a product of $f(x_i\mid \theta)$. You gave a formula for $f(x_i\mid \theta)$. You substitute each data value in for its particular $x_i$.

> and how to make a plot of prior, likelihood and posterior distribution.

Wait, you don't know how to draw plots of functions? All three are simply functions of $\theta$. You should plot those functions for values that are interesting (where they're not really small) - for the likelihood and posterior, this will be values reasonably close to $\hat{\theta}$

Comment: Thank you one more time. I just need to use the R for plots

Comment: Ok so for each value 5,6,9,5,4 I , so I substitute the x with 5, then with 6 and so on? And on the end I have 5 different plots?

Comment: f(x_i\mid \theta)=\theta(1-\theta)^{x_i} in this formula

Comment: This is the right formula?

Comment: Yes, you substitute each one in (unless you can see how to combine them so you only have to compute a *sufficient statistic*, which makes it easier). No you don't have 5 functions for the likelihood. Read the second sentence of my answer again please. Yes, that's the right function to put the $x_i$ in, but each is only one term in the likelihood (again, see that second sentence).

Answer (score 1):

An informative prior would require some prior knowledge about $\theta$: for instance, if you know both the mean and the variance on $\theta$, you can use a Beta prior
$$
\theta \sim f(\theta) = \dfrac{
\theta^{\alpha-1}(1-\theta)^{\beta-1}}
{B(\alpha,\beta)}
$$
and pick $(\alpha,\beta)$ according to this prior information...

A noninformative prior is derived from a formal rule like Jeffreys', which leads to the Beta $B(1/2,1.2)$ prior.

Comment: I'm just so confused! It is my first stat homework. So I just pick some random alpha and beta and put it in the formula above

Comment: Certainly acceptable for a first homework!!!