# Non-informative prior of a geometric distribution

Tags: bayesian, prior, geometric-distribution, uninformative-prior

If we are given a standard geometric distribution $(1-p)^{x-1} p$, with $0<p<1$ what would be a suitable non-informative prior for this?

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395402/calculating-jeffreys-prior-for-geometric-distribution,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50646/bayes-specify-informative-and-uninformative-prior,

Comment: There is no such thing as a non-informative prior. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20535/7224